# How do I access Sinatra params using a symbol?

Tags: sinatra

In Sinatra, I use params to get the key/value passed through the URL query string. I noticed I can use either a string or a symbol as the key to get the value. So if the URL is:

```
http://localhost:4567/x?a=1&b=2
```

Then:

```
params[:a] # => "1"
params["a"] # => "1"
params.to_s # => '{"name"=>"x", "a"=>"1", "b"=>"2"}'
params.class # => Hash
```

I can tell params is a Hash. But this doesn't seem to be a common behavior of a Hash.

```
h = {"a" => "1", "b" => "2"}
h["a"] # => "1"
h[:a] # => nil
```

Can someone please explain how this is achieved through Sinatra?

Answer (score 18):

Always a good idea to have a read of the [source](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/). Specifically, the [`indifferent_params` method](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/cab56ed7d64b9ffb6d4df48cb8d7d3153890f3ee/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L910).

```
# Enable string or symbol key access to the nested params hash.
def indifferent_params(params)
  params = indifferent_hash.merge(params)
  params.each do |key, value|
    next unless value.is_a?(Hash)
    params[key] = indifferent_params(value)
  end
end
```

As the comment states, it's this method (invoked on [line 704](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/2d604ccfe84da7595d2de4befa7bbe38f9d4629c/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L704) of the same file) that allows string and symbol access to the `params` hash.

Comment: I don't know if this is possible with ruby, but if they could override the hash access method (`[]`), wouldn't it be better to allow this method to convert symbols to strings rather than duplicating every pair? Seems like a relatively expensive design choice for what benefits it gives.

Comment: The [current implementation](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/6ce8a94005397695f0fd2cc241cd09fb325dd567/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1060-L1062) is much lighter: `Hash.new {|hash,key| hash[key.to_s] if Symbol === key }`, meaning if the key is a Symbol, try with the String version of the key.