# Why would one use String keys for a hash over symbols

Tags: ruby, sinatra, symbols

This question is supposed to be the reverse of this one: [Why use symbols as hash keys in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8189416/1313143)

As you can see, everyone agrees that symbols are the most logical choice for hash keys. However, I'm building a web application with the sinatra framework, and the `request` object is a hash that contains `String`s as keys. Can anyone explain why this would be a design choice?

Comment: Note that with Sinatra you can use [either a string or a symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619707/accessing-sinatra-params-using-a-symbol).

Comment: "everyone agrees that symbols are the most logical choice for hash keys", no, they don't. It is a programmer's choice, sometimes based on herd-instinct, but more often based on what made the most sense at the time. Between strings and symbols, I use symbols usually, but I have also used regex patterns or even arrays as my keys, because it was expedient. A Hash is a container, just like an Array, and can contain all sorts of things. What we stick in there is up to us and should make sense for that application. If we're talking only about a parameter hash in Sinatra, then see @Phrogz answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the source of the keys--the query string--is made up of strings, so searching through this string for keys, it is most directly convenient to index the hash via the strings.

Every Symbol that is created in the Ruby runtime is allocated and never released. There is a theoretical (but unlikely) DOS attack available by sending hundreds of thousands of requests with unique query string parameters. If these were symbolized, each request would slowly grow the runtime memory pool.

Strings, on the other hand, may be garbage collected. Thousands of unique strings handled across various requests will eventually go away, with no long-term impact.

**Edit**: Note that with [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), symbols are also *available* for accessing the `params` hash. However, this is done by creating a hash that is indexed by strings, and converting symbols (in your code) to strings when you make a request. Unless you do something like the following:

```
params.each{ |key,_| key.to_sym }
```

...you are not at risk of any symbol pseudo-DOS attack.

Comment: The `request` object holds much more than the query string. HTTP headers, for one. Since these are always the same, symbols would seem a more logical choice in terms of memory consumption. Also, Rack uses string keys everywhere.

Comment: you are confusing `params` with `request` I guess?

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester Yes, sorry, I thought you were using the Sinatra `params` object. instead of the Rack `request`.

Comment: sorry for the confusion caused. I didn't know `request` belonged to Rack. This is only my first ruby project ever.